# Energy norm: what is the intuition behind?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Last week I've read the following definition of Energy Norm (along with the definitions of a distance, Euclidean norm, p-norm, etc..: we were talking about metric spaces).

Specifically, for $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ positive definite, the energy norm of $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is defined as follows:
$$
||x||_{A} := \sqrt{x^T A x} 
$$

I felt completely lost. Is there any intuition / geometrical representation behind this concept that may help me to understand it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you already seen it with another name?

Comment: I think it may be more commonly called a weighted norm.

Comment: Now it is all clear. Thank you! Grazie! Danke! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the name (it may be more commonly known as the "weighted norm"), but geometrically you can think of it as the normal $2$-norm, except the level sets are hyperellipsoids with axes coincident with the eigenvectors of $A$ (when $A=I$ for the normal $2$-norm, the level sets are hyperspheres).